# "Number" or "numbers"?

Tags: plural-forms, subjects, singular

Is there a difference between using "number" and "numbers" when referring to multiple numbers?

For example, when calling a merchant to inquire about multiple orders, should I say:

> I need RMAs for order **numbers** 1 and 2.

or

> I need RMAs for order **number** 1 and 2.

This question might sound stupid, but I'm not sure what the main subject is. Is "number" the subject and therefore should I use "numbers"? Or are the order numbers (1 and 2) the subject, so should I keep "number" singular?

Comment: Personally, I'd say *"for **orders** number 1 and 2"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually hear that as "Order numbers 1 and 2", with the "s". Fumble's comment gives a good way to get around it anyway.

Comment: Hi TecBrat, can you elaborate on your answer please? When possible, answers with more information are usually better :)